# how to hide id from an url using htaccess mod-rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using this code in my htaccess to rewrite my urls

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]*)-([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?menu_id=$1&menu=$2 [qsappend]
```

This rewrites my URL to:

```
www.site.com/1-home.html
```

Where `1` is the id(menu_id) and `home` is the name of menu.

I have been looking around for a solution where I would be able to rewrite the URLs to:

```
www.site.com/home.html
```

Hiding the menu_id part.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: if you hide the menu id how would you know where to go back to if menu_id is required for the index.php to show it? Does just `site.com/index.php?menu=home` opens the home page for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how.

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?menu_id=1&menu=$1 [qsappend]
```

**Edit:** You have to compensate for the fact that you won't know the menu id. for instance i put a 1 there, bc i assume you want all your menu id's to be one.

Here is your code broken down:

```
# here is where your id is located in the code
#               |  This is the dash in your code
#               |   |  This is your home part
#               v   v   v
RewriteRule ([0-9]*)-([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?menu_id=$1&menu=$2 [qsappend]
#           |_____________________| |__________________________|
#                  Rewrite                     script

# www.site.com/1-home.html
```

Comment: read my edit, when you remove the id you have to compensate for that, bc now you won't be able to pass the menu id via the `GET` method

Comment: @user3627000 try the code again, I made an edit. but notice how all menu id's will be one.

Comment: as you suggested this gives me a mysql error due to missing GET id. is there any work around for this. I am pretty new to this. your help is truly appreciated

Comment: @user3627000 is this `menu_id=1` in your htaccess ?

Comment: no... menu_id is in my url. 1-home.html, 2-about-us.html. without the menu_id in url the page does not show (mysql error). i sometimes use the same name for my menu so the id part helps differentiate it from each other.

Comment: with that being said the problem isn't htaccess only, as you have php/mysql errors too. its time to rethink your website structure.